# Password Protected at Un installation time

Tags: android, security

I am trying make security app for keeping tracking your lost phone.I made app as device admin app so it can't uninstall directly but using unregister app to device admin we can un- installed it.so i wants make password protected app at un-installation time.when user try to un-install the app one dialog box appear to ask password.i know some apps do that functionality.can anyone knows about it?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540002/how-to-prevent-an-application-from-being-uninstalled

Comment: @twntee i saw already so much questions in SO but can't find any solution for that.

Comment: because, we can't prevent our app from being uninstalled, it all upto user !, or who would like his app to get uninstalled ;)

Comment: yeah but any one,who is not the owner of phone also can un install any app so user has to enter correct password for un installing app.can we make like this?i found some apps are there in market so it is possible to do it.

Comment: yes, and the above link talks about those apps, morever hide your apps launcher icon and notifications, no one will ever know if there was an app ! like stealth mode :)

Comment: But in setting screen we can find that app.so how to make app being uninstalled with password.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this on a stock device. If you want to prevent people from uninstalling your app you have to make it a system app (part of the ROM). Even so, on recent Android versions users can choose to disable it. On Android 4.3 you have the option of marking the device admin (system app) as a 'device owner' so that users cannot deactivate it. This is obviously not available on earlier versions.