# Password Protect android settings

Tags: android

I want to develop an app to help parents monitor kids overuse of android equipments. So, I need to "block" kids from uninstalling that app. I know that it's not polite (or even possible) to simply block my app uninstall, but I would want to only allow parents with a key code to be able to uninstall it. I have been researching but I'm unable to find the right answer. 
What approach do u guys suggest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540002/how-to-prevent-an-application-from-being-uninstalled

Comment: I have read that question, its similar, but its kinda old. Since 2011 i'm sure that many features changed. For instance, with android 5.0 we have a new screen pinning API that lets you temporarily restrict users from leaving your task or being interrupted by notifications, i can use this on my project for another subject... I just wanted to know if something new came up since 2011. Thanks anyway.