# Possible to prevent uninstallation of app?

Tags: android, uninstallation, device-admin

Is it possible for an Android device administrator app to disable uninstallation of itself?

The default behavior is that the app's uninstall button is grayed out, unless the user unchecks it from the list of device administrators. However, I've seen MDM apps that goes the extra step to disallow users from unchecking the app from the list of device administrators (e.g. Citrix XenMobile). How is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent an application from being uninstalled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540002/how-to-prevent-an-application-from-being-uninstalled)