# Android How to prevent my app to uninstall?

Tags: android

I am working on a locker application and for this I want to disable the uninstall option from app manager so any other user can not delete my app. But for uninstalling I want to give the option with in the application, Please suggest me how can I achieve this in Android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent an application from being uninstalled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540002/how-to-prevent-an-application-from-being-uninstalled)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to enable deviceAdmin to disable Force Stop and Uninstall features. This is handled by the Device Admin API which handles enterprise/app policy management.