# How to prevent an application from being uninstalled from Letv,Mi,RedMi device?

Tags: android, device, uninstallation

I read a [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7540002/6711591) , it is only some how helpful for me , but the answers are not working in **LEtv,Mi and RedMi** devices .

My appliation has [Device Administration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) rights, then also the applications is uninstalled from  **LEtv,Mi & RedMi** devices .
any one have solution for preventing app uninstall  from **LEtv,Mi & RedMi** devices?

**my ManifestFile**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidsrc.sampledeviceadmin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name=".SampleDeviceAdminReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**device_admin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <uses-policies>
        <force-lock />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Comment: The android version of those mobile is android 6 and above. right?

Comment: yes it is above 6.0

Comment: post your manifest file

Comment: Besides having Device Administration rights  
Do check this GPS tracking software:  
[GPS Tracking Software - Free and Open Source System - Traccar](https://www.traccar.org/)  
you can hide it from the menu or launcher and name it as Device Settings as they have done and also Default Android settings icon is used as an app icon. After first start, the app removes itself from the launcher.

Comment: i don't want to hide from launcher.