# What package or event can I use so that my apk can not uninstall?

Tags: android, events, action, system, uninstallation

What package or event can I use so that my apk can not uninstall or execute an action when it wants to uninstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible.

You can provide messaging to the user and make it slightly more difficult when uninstalling using the admin api.

have a look here  -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7540037/1856361

Comment: Thanks @MatthewShearer, that's what I was looking for, that before the user could uninstall the application, enter a password to be able to uninstall it, I will start reading about the device administrator api.

Comment: no problem, please mark it as the correct answer if so